# how to display DC. Js chart / numberdisplay?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create a numberdisplay chart for my dashboard.The problem is : I can't display the value. It displays 'NAN'

```
var byWomen = cf.dimension(function (d) { return d.Women; });
var byWomenGroup = byWomen.groupAll().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.Women; })

dc.numberDisplay("#totalwom")
                    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return +d })
                    .group(byWomenGroup)
                    .formatNumber(d3.format(".g"));
```

Comment: you've got return d.Women in the dimension and then in the group as well, on reduceSum? Is that right? Or should it be reduceCount?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the total of women so I use reduceSum for the group byWomenGroup  and byWomen dimension. The reduceCount works with this code but I want to Sum the values.

Comment: Try changing your group to:      cf.groupAll().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.Women; })

Comment: Maybe `.Women` is arriving as a string and you need to convert it to a number in `reduceSum`. I agree with @Kevin that using `.Women` as the key and also the reduction is highly unusual. Posting a sample of your data could help.